# How do you design a cricket sound?

Tags: sound-design, ambience, synthesis

Does anyone have any tricks for designing a sound like a cricket or crickets? I live in Scotland and recording actual crickets obviously isn't an option!

Comment: @graeme should i send you some?

Comment: There are really no crickets in Scotland? That's fascinating.

Answer (score 8):

Hi Graeme, 
I like crickets and I'm designing a cricket machine on [puredata](http://puredata.info/).
I've made a good cricket so far but it still lacks some frequencies.
My puredata bible for sound design is here: http://obiwannabe.co.uk/tutorials/html/tutorials_main.html

First I made a recording with some real crickets so I studied the waveform and the harmonic spectrum. A chirp is made by 4 impulses (20ms each every 30ms). The dominant frequency is 
4170Hz with some 8340, 12480, 16680Hz (a flat C note).  Now I'm working on the resonance.
I didn't try it but I'm sure you can do a great cricket with the Operator (Ableton Live instrument) and with many other vst synths. The advantage with pd is that you can simulate the strange tempo/nontempo of the nature.
I can give you the puredata patch if you like but I don't know how to attach files here.

Comment: How long have you been using PD?  Do you have previous experience with languages?

Comment: When I started with pd two years ago I already knew some max/msp stuff, not very much though. Now I'm using pd a lot and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're any good with your own voice try this: http://www.ehow.com/how_4702844_chirp-like-cricket.html

and if you're not try a synth! Base the sound on a  white noise hiss and fiddle around with other pre-sets (those that sound like a ringing phone) until you have something clear and resonant. There's plenty of free cricket sound effects on-line if you need inspiration/a reference point.

Failing that- go to your local reptile supply shop and buy a box of crickets!

Happy noise making!

Helen @LenSound

Answer (score 1):

answering a question with a question: If you live in a country that does not have crickets are you aware of when/how/why their presence occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pleased to announce that I've just published a new tool called the [Cricket Chirp Tool,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsrXAB7MsfY) as well as some videos on this topic of Cricket Chirp SFX. An extensive written tutorial is found [here on my blog,](https://www.jpintericsound.com.au/jpintericsound-blog/2016/11/7/cricket-chirp-synthesis) which includes some background and analysis techniques.

To introduce a very basic technique:

1. Apply Ring modulation to a Sine Wave. Tune the main Osc to a high Octave like C7, which is 2khz.
2. If you can change the Ring Mod wave, change it to a Triangle, and tune it in a low octave so that it's between 35hz - 70hz. This creates a nice buzzing, with sidebands in a very narrow frequency range.
3. Then modulate the chirp syllables how you like, I prefer to use a pulse-wave LFO, but custom Envs also work, they just need to be very fast.

A number of other techniques are demonstrated in the following video:

And thank you Andy Farnell, I love your work!

Answer (score 0):

If you like I have two cricket recordings from Australia that I could send your way. First is a shotgun mic on a single cricket chriping loudly and constantly with lttle variation. The other is a stereo recording which features a group of crickets chriping at regular intervals. Into the recording a second group of crickets joins in. Send me an email to kyle [at] cannedgeek.com if those are useful to you.

I really should have more. There have been some great varieties of crickets I have been hearing this summer in my area. I am happy to just send those to you fo free - although if you have something to trade from Scotland in return that would be even better. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a cricket, but to get a good synthesized cicada sound I'd try taking a recording of a baseball card being flipped by the spokes of a bike tire and pitch it up like 2 octaves to get that cool cicada sound effect. I'd also experiment with different types of material - like an old plastic credit card or plastic spoon.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this on Music of Sound:

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/cicadas-meet-pitch-shift